# npm install aspose.cells fails

Tags: node.js, svg, xlsx, aspose

I want to explore using aspose.cells to convert XLSX to SVG.

For that purpose when I try to install aspose.cells using npm install aspose.cells.
(After having run npm install java)

It fails with the following error

Any help/pointers in this regard is appreciated

```
$ npm install aspose.cells
code 1
npm ERR! path /Volumes/NEW_DISK/user/sudheer.hr/nodejs/xlsx/node_modules/aspose.cells/node_modules/java
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.2 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Volumes/NEW_DISK/user/sudheer.hr/nodejs/xlsx/node_modules/aspose.cells/node_modules/java/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/sudheer.hr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.9.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/sudheer.hr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.9.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/sudheer.hr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.9.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Volumes/NEW_DISK/user/sudheer.hr/nodejs/xlsx/node_modules/aspose.cells/node_modules/java',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2884:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_typedarray_contents.h:34:43: error: no member named 'GetContents' in 'v8::ArrayBuffer'
npm ERR!       data   = static_cast<char*>(buffer->GetContents().Data()) + byte_offset;
npm ERR!                                   ~~~~~~~~^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:201:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/local/bin/node" "/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/NEW_DISK/user/sudheer.hr/nodejs/xlsx/node_modules/aspose.cells/node_modules/java
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sudheer.hr/.npm/_logs/2022-12-01T08_39_36_852Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that Python 2.x is installed properly. Your issue might be related to configurations on your end. Could you please check and follow the instructions on the suggested [document](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/nodejs-java/getting-started/#mac). Maybe you you could try to conduct/setup a fresh installation of Aspose.Cells for Node.js via Java on some other MAC machine (if possible).

Moreover, you may also post your queries or issue via dedicated [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I hit the same issue as OP when using node 18 but had no issues when using node 16